# what is causing this buffer overrun warning over 64 bit VS2012 compile environment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, 64-bit

I have a working application compiled using VS2010 64 bit environment - while trying to migrate it to VS2012 compiler (C++11) i get a C6386 warning and can't seem to find the root cause:

here is the code snippet that yields the warning:

```
Packet::Packet(const Packet& oOther)
{
   m_vData.assign(oOther.m_vData.begin(),oOther.m_vData.end());
   if(NULL != oOther.m_pValueChecks)
   {
      m_pValueChecks = new set<string>*[oOther.m_vData.size()];
      for(size_t i = 0; i < oOther.m_vData.size(); ++i)
      {

        if(NULL == oOther.m_pValueChecks[i])
        {
             m_pValueChecks[i] = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
/// compiler warns on the below line
             m_pValueChecks[i] = new set<string>(oOther.m_pValueChecks[i]->begin(), oOther.m_pValueChecks[i]->end());
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Packet class definition:

```
class Packet
{
public:
    Packet();
    Packet(const Packet&);

    .....

    vector<pair<string,pair<FieldType,Field> > > m_vData;
    set<string> ** m_pValueChecks;
}
```

the Warning generated:

`c:\<my_path_and_file>(3331): warning C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'm_pValueChecks':  the writable size is 'oOther.m_vData.public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl std::vector<struct std::pair<string,struct std::pair<enum Packet::FieldType,class Field> >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<string,struct std::pair<enum Packet::FieldType,class Field> > > >::size(void)const ()*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written.: Lines: 3312, 3313, 3314, 3315, 3316, 3317, 3318, 3319, 3320, 3322, 3323, 3325, 3331, 3323, 3325, 3331`

as the compile environment is 64 bit, the `oOther.m_vData.size()` is of type `size_t` which is 64 bit unsigned integer on 64 bit environment, so the `for` loop is iterating correctly on the range, and `m_pValueChecks` contains enough allocated items to satisfy the assignment.

why the warning is generated?

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocate an "array" of pointers to sets? The first problem here is that you are dynamically allocating memory, when you have the very good `std::vector` collection for what you are doing. The second problem is that you are using pointers, in C++ there is seldom any need to use pointers. If you don't use pointer in the collection, then a simple assignment would have been enough.

Comment: Present a [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Abyx: No need to act like that here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's not acting. it's the code which is horrible.

Comment: @Abyx: Let's remain professional please.

Comment: Well, sir, your code is not particularly beautiful indeed. Please remove all the unnecessary pointers and dynamic memory allocation. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit both the code and the question are very unprofessional, but... whatever, never mind

Comment: @Abyx - indeed the code is awful, but it is not mine - i am in charge to migrating it to VS2012 environment. re-factoring is always an option - but please try to focus on the problem itself - the learning might be useful in other locations as well. thanks for the comments

Comment: @Jefffrey please check my comment to Abyx

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - check the comment list on my question - one comment before mine to you...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: my mistake - it should be Abyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - continue digging into the scenario - i have found that the project contains /analyze switch which forces the Code Analysis option of VS2012 to always run.

when removing this switch, the above (nasty i agree) code compiles without any warning.

now, as this specific code compiles with no warning on VS2010 64 bit environment, then VS2010 vs. VS2012 code analysis rules differences are the primary suspect for the warning.

currently, i've passed this roadblock in my migration efforts, i'll try to continue understand the rules thing differences later on. if someone can shade some light on it it would be great to post it here.

**EDIT:**
i have found out that Code Analyzer is not working on VS2010 - the compiler switch is ignored, which explains why this code is compiling. Anyhow a proper re-factor is required.

**EDIT 2**

Folks, after intensive thinking (almost 6 months) i finally found the root cause...

```
m_pValueChecks = new set<string>*[oOther.m_vData.size()];
for(size_t i = 0; i < oOther.m_vData.size(); ++i)
{

  if(NULL == oOther.m_pValueChecks[i])
  {
       m_pValueChecks[i] = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
      /// commpiler warns on the below line
      m_pValueChecks[i] = new set<string>(oOther.m_pValueChecks[i]->begin(), oOther.m_pValueChecks[i]->end());
  }
}
```

The reasons is because the `for` loop increments the `i` index using `++i`, which means first the `i` variable is incremented, then being used.

This means there might be a chance the `i` variable will be more than `oOther.m_vData.size()` which is the size of the `m_pValueChecks` allocated array.

Changing the `for` floop to `for(size_t i = 0; i < oOther.m_vData.size(); i++)` removed the warning.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that in VS2012 the `new` operator uses aligned allocators. May you try using a `__declspec(align(16))` on either your struct or in your variable? (Or use `/Zp16`)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing `other.m_pValueChecks` with `other.m_vData` in a few places. This could result in memory corruption due to mismatching array sizes.

Instead of this ghastly double-pointer approach, consider putting your sets inside another container type and let the language do all this for you, safely.

Comment: while your suggestion was also my initial response when i've seen this code - simply refactor this code (which is not mine) - i am looking for the knowledge behind this problem. refactoring the code will solve the problem but hide away the warning mechanism which i'm seeking to understand

Comment: @NirMH: I just told you what the problem is.

Comment: which is the mix of `other.m_pValueChecks` and `other.m_vData`? notice this code compiles (and runs) perfectly in VS2010 64 bit environment

Comment: @NirMH: Invoking undefined behaviour may appear to work. Doesn't mean it's right. Read your code to see how you're apparently referencing the wrong container at various points inside your loop (unless there's some constraint you've not identified to us). I'm not going to spell it out for you.

Comment: @NirMH It would be possible to identify the particular reason for this warning if you created a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Possibly, after doing this you will identify the problem yourself.